# Is it possible to represent non-ASCII characters?

Tags: python-2.7, ascii

Does anyone know of a way to represent Non-ASCII symbols such as this symbol "ŷ" on python in a print statement?

Comment: Use Unicode....  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the UTF-8 coding system.

The first line of your Python file should be:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If this doesn't work, try wrapping your string with unicode(string).

```
print unicode("éáóý");
```

If this still doesn't work, try adding these lines before all code but after # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import sys
if not hasattr(sys, "setdefaultencoding"):
    reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Finally, make sure that you are saving the file as UTF-8 and that your console supports unicode characters.

Comment: No luck ;/, it keeps asking turning into another character.

Comment: @user3720526: If you're trying to display one character and getting another, then you need to say that in your question.

Comment: I am sorry, I will try to be more specific in future questions from now on.

Comment: I updated my answer with more suggestions, please try them too.

Comment: Yup, it worked. I'm going to have to study unicode on python more now.