# Cyrillic characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, cyrillic

The function returns places in radius using the Google Places API. To be exact, I use [this](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places) library to handle the task.

The problem is that cyrillic symbols are shown like this:

> ÐÐž Ð¡Ð±ÐµÑ€Ð±Ð°Ð½Ðº Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð¸, ÐšÐ¸ÐµÐ²ÑÐºÐ¾Ðµ
>   Ð¾Ñ‚Ð´ÐµÐ»ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ â„–14

I tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112984/is-it-possible-to-represent-non-ascii-characters) suggestions. I also tried this:

```
pname = place.name
uni = unicode(place.name)
```

And this:

```
convertedname = pname.encode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict')
```

Nothing helped. What else can I try?

Comment: What is your wanted output?

Comment: ah, I should have mentioned. Like that: Інтеграл Банк, Український індустріал, etc. The function should be able to return Russian, Ukrainian and English

Comment: What are the actual bytes that you are trying to print?

Comment: Like that: list(bytearray("надра")) 
[208, 189, 208, 176, 208, 180, 209, 128, 208, 176]. And why does it give more bytes in output than letters in string?

Comment: That's not a very good resource you are linking to in the question, by the way.  There's a reason the only answer has a downvote.  This is not a very uncommon question; you should easily find dozens of duplicates with better answers.

Comment: Also, obligatory reading: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: totally agree that it's not the link to be trusted, actually tried a lot of other suggestions. Thanks for the link, I will read it for sure

Answer (score 0):

> > list(bytearray("надра"))
> >
> > [208, 189, 208, 176, 208, 180, 209, 128, 208, 176]

That's UTF-8.  If your output terminal is set up for UTF-8, you should basically need no encoding or decoding at all.  But the proper way to read that string is to use `string.decode('utf-8')` to turn it into a proper Unicode string, then encode it before output to whatever encoding your terminal supports (looks vaguely like ... [code page 1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) or [iso-8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2)?).

<sup>https://tripleee.github.io/8bit#0xd0 shows 208 (0xD0) being mapped to Đ in six different encodings, so I conjecture that you are using one of those.  The rest is speculation on my part.</sup>

So, basically,

```
pname=place.name.decode('utf-8')
```

Apparently, you also need to encode it to some suitable output encoding for your console, or set up your console to properly support UTF-8.  If indeed your terminal is presently set up for cp1250, it does not support Cyrillic output at all.

Answer (score 0):

My terminal and browser encoding is utf-8 and the problem was while displaying text in browser. The problem was solved after i uncommented lines in webapp2 .py file:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), 'index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

which consider templating and such stuff. Your answer helped me to come to the solution. Thanks!